# Another way of instantiating an Object in java?

Tags: java, android, object, android-studio-3.0

I am referring to android studio here, because this is where i saw this method of instantiating an object. More specifically while creating an object of Toast class,

```
Toast mytoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Here we are creating an object of class Toast, but my question is how is this possible ?

I thought it is only possible via new, newInstance(), clone(), or deserialization. But i am pretty sure that type of object instantiating, which i mentioned above, does not fall under any of those methods of instantiating.

So what type of method of instantiation is followed for the Toast class ?

Comment: go inside `makeText`, you will see the magic

Comment: As Ravi mentioned: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java#259.